# HttpURLConnection doesn't submit POST data (Android)

Tags: java, android, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I'm submitting POST parameters in my Android app, however, none are received by the server (`request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()` in Play Framework returns an empty Map). Here's the AsyncTask code used to submit the request:

```
private static AsyncTask<String, Void, String> register = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String email = params[0], username = params[1], password = params[2];
            try {
                URL               url = new URL(REGISTER);
                HttpURLConnection conn;
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                String            urlParams        = URLEncoder.encode("username=" + username + "&email=" + email + "&password=" + password, "UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(urlParams.length()));
                conn.connect();
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(urlParams);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                int resp = conn.getResponseCode();
                Object content = conn.getContent();
                conn.disconnect();
                if(resp != 200)
                    return ERROR + "Bad response: " + resp + ", ";// + conn.getContent();
                return content.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException occurred: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ERROR + e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    };
```

I do plan on making something prettier, but I need to make this work first. Every answer so far suggested something I've already done (e. g. `connect()`, setting `Content-Length`, closing the Writer after finished, getting the response) and it still doesn't work. Connection is received by the server, but the body is empty and server returns `400`.

Comment: You might have to encode individual param values (and param keys).

Comment: Are you sure, you need to encode POST parameters? Normally, it is required for GET params only.

Comment: Not encoding params solved it, but now I'm even more puzzled why is that? On the other hand, if I don't encode params, I can't allow `&` (and other characters with special meaning) in any of the fields or I have to encode them manually

Comment: Encoding parameters individually works as expected as well and of course better than not encoding anything. If any of you could provide any explanation, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: Obvious answer to my first comment: encoding '&' doesn't make it a form anymore (duh!). On the other hand, Play returned null even when getting the response as text, which wasn't really expected, I should have gotten something along the lines of`username%3Dtest%26pass%3Dsmth`, right? @JinKwon, @EugeneKrivenja feel free to submit an answer now, I've forgotten that you don't get the notification unless mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to either set the content-length or call `connect()`: these are both automatic. But you need to set the content *type* via the API, not via a request property. Otherwise it gets overwritten by the API's default, which is why not encoding fixed it.

Comment: How do you set the content type via the API and not request property?